# Get exactly the same assembly when compiling in .NET

Tags: .net, msbuild, compilation, .net-assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine whether .NET assemblies were built from the same source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940857/determine-whether-net-assemblies-were-built-from-the-same-source)

I want to compare assemblies in .NET to check for any changes. After looking around the web, I found out that the compiler changes the build date, the version revision (if not explicitly specified) and many other things. Is there, by any chance, an option in msbuild to get exactly the same result with two different builds ?

Comment: What do you want to compare?  You could always use reflection to do a binary compare of member bodies.

Comment: Can you ignore these factors in the comparison? Might be a little more complicated, but it's definitely better practice.

Comment: Thanks for referring me to that question, using ildasm might be a possible approach.

Answer (score 1):

A Visual Studio project has a file named `AssemblyInfo` which contains metadata about the assembly.

You can set the version information there.

Here is an example of a section in an `AssemblyInfo` file:

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is a changing MVID (Module Version Identifier) value too which cannot be controlled.

Comment: Exactly, the MVID is one of the changes I'm trying to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Using ILDASM while ignoring specific tokens is an possible approach. Thanks to chibacity.