# Retrieve MVID of an assembly from c#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

How to retrieve the module version identifier (MVID) of a .NET assembly using reflection in c#?

Comment: see if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940857/determine-whether-net-assemblies-were-built-from-the-same-source

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Should be:

```
var myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); //or whatever
var mvid = myAssembly.ManifestModule.ModuleVersionID;
```

There can be other modules in an assembly, but the ManifestModule would be the one that "identifies" the assembly itself.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a sample that doesn't use Reflection to load the assembly but instead uses [System.Reflection.Metadata](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata):

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    PEReader reader = new PEReader(stream);
    var metadataReader = reader.GetMetadataReader();
    var mvidHandle = metadataReader.GetModuleDefinition().Mvid;
    var mvid = metadataReader.GetGuid(mvidHandle);
}
```

And here's a sample of using [Mono.Cecil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Cecil):

```
var module = Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(filePath);
var mvid = module.Mvid;
```

And here's an example of a standalone code to read the MVID without any dependencies. It is a stripped-down version of Mono.Cecil in a single file:
https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MetadataTools/blob/master/src/PEFile/ImageReader.cs